# Conditional statement on framesubtitle: unwanted effect

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I want to get something like this:

(a) frametitle
or
(b) frametitle | framesubtitle

But the following codes add | after every frametitle with/without framesubtitle, Anyone could help me? What's going on?

```
                \documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
            
            \usepackage{color,xcolor,colortbl}
             \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
               \usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
            
            \mode<presentation>
            \usetheme{default}
            
            %--------------------------------------
            %   Colors  Setup
            %--------------------------------------
               \definecolor {beamerred}   {rgb}{0.55,0,0.1}
               \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamerred!90!black}
               % inner color
               \usecolortheme{orchid}
               % outer color
              \usecolortheme{whale}
            
            %--------------------------------------
            %   Fonts  Setup
            %--------------------------------------
                \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}              % math font
                \setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large
                                                               %series=\bfseries,
                                                               }  % frame title font size
                
                \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}        % footnote font size
            
            % inner theme
               \useinnertheme{rectangles}    % use rectangles
                %itemize list
                \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]            % item symbol
                \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]         % subitem symbol
                \setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\normalsize}
                %enumerate list
                \setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[numbered]        % item symbol
                \setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[numbered]     % item symbol
                   \setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{size=\normalsize} % item symbol font size
            
                    
            %-------------------------------------------
            %        Outer Theme
            %-------------------------------------------
                        % navigation
                \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
            
                   % frametitle
                      \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%%%%
                    \begin{textblock*}{0.88\paperwidth}(0cm,0\paperheight)
                        \begin{tcolorbox}[
                            arc=0pt,
                            boxrule=0pt,
                            left skip =0pt,
                            right skip=0pt,
                            %height=\frametitleheight,width=0.15\paperwidth,
                            height=0.10\paperheight,
                            width=0.88\paperwidth,
                            coltext=white,
                            skin=bicolor,
                            valign=center,
                            halign=left,
                            interior style={%%%
                                                   left color=structure!95!black,
                                                   right color=structure
                                                   }%%%
                            ]
                            \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty
                                 \insertframetitle    
                                       \else 
                                          \insertframetitle|\small \insertframesubtitle
                                       \fi
                        \end{tcolorbox}
                    \end{textblock*}
                    \hfill
                    \begin{textblock*}{0.118\paperwidth}(0.882\paperwidth,0\paperheight)
                        \begin{tcolorbox}[
                            arc=0pt,
                            boxrule=0pt,
                            left skip =0pt,
                            right skip=0pt,
                            %height=\frametitleheight,width=0.15\paperwidth,
                            height=0.10\paperheight,
                            width=0.12\paperwidth,
                            coltext=white,
                            skin=bicolor,
                            valign=center,
                            halign=right,
                            interior style={%%%
                                                   left color=structure,
                                                   right color=structure!90!white
                                                   }%%%
                            ]
                            \scriptsize \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
                        \end{tcolorbox}
                    \end{textblock*}
                    \vspace{0.10\paperheight}
                }%%%%
            
            % footline  
                \setbeamertemplate{footline}{
                       \vspace{2mm}
                    \begin{textblock*}{1.01\paperwidth}(0.92\paperwidth,0.96\paperheight)
                        {logo here}
                    \end{textblock*}
                }
            
            \mode
            <all> 
            
            %----------------------------------------
            %   Path of Figures
            %----------------------------------------
            
            
            %------------------------------------------
            %           begin of document
            %------------------------------------------
            \begin{document}
            \section{first }
            
            \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Limits}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item first
            \item second
            \item third
            \end{itemize}
            \end{frame}
            
            \begin{frame}
            \frametitle{Limits}
            \framesubtitle{Monotone Sequence}
            
            \begin{itemize}
            \item first
            \item second
            \item third
            \end{itemize}
            \end{frame}
            %------------------------------------------
            %             end of  document
            %------------------------------------------
            \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete example? For instance, how is the `textblock*` environment defined? Please provide code we can actually run as is to reproduce your issue. The way your code example currently is leaves a lot of guesswork for us.

Comment: If I do the required guesswork (so add `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` and `\usepackage{textbox}`, add `\documentclass{beamer}` and a document body containing a few frames with and without titles and subtitles) I can't reproduce your issue. For me only the frames having a title and subtitle get the dash.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll re-edit the post and give a minimal example.

Comment: @Skillmon I use \usepackage{textpos} and changed \usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox} to \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}, the unwanted dash is still there.  I also run the demo online using overleaf, still the unwanted dash. A little strange

Comment: The `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` has nothing to do with this. That was just guesswork to get `tcolorbox` to work in most cases (as it loads most of its libraries, so chances are high that the ones required by your code were part of it). See my answer for the actual reason why your code fails. Same for the `textbox`, that was just to get your example running, without caring whether the alignment will be correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're not comparing `\insertframesubtitle` to `\@empty`, but to the control symbol `\@`, as you didn't use `\makeatletter` to turn `@` into a letter such that it can be part of a control word.

Hence just putting `\makeatletter...\makeatother` around your `\setbeamertemplate{frametitile}` will fix your issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{color,xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{default}

%--------------------------------------
%   Colors  Setup
%--------------------------------------
\definecolor {beamerred}   {rgb}{0.55,0,0.1}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamerred!90!black}
% inner color
\usecolortheme{orchid}
% outer color
\usecolortheme{whale}

%--------------------------------------
%   Fonts  Setup
%--------------------------------------
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}              % math font
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large
%series=\bfseries,
}  % frame title font size

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}        % footnote font size

% inner theme
\useinnertheme{rectangles}    % use rectangles
%itemize list
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[square]            % item symbol
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]         % subitem symbol
\setbeamerfont{itemize item}{size=\normalsize}
%enumerate list
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[numbered]        % item symbol
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[numbered]     % item symbol
\setbeamerfont{enumerate item}{size=\normalsize} % item symbol font size


%-------------------------------------------
%        Outer Theme
%-------------------------------------------
% navigation
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% frametitle
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%%%%
  \begin{textblock*}{0.88\paperwidth}(0cm,0\paperheight)
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        arc=0pt,
        boxrule=0pt,
        left skip =0pt,
        right skip=0pt,
        %height=\frametitleheight,width=0.15\paperwidth,
        height=0.10\paperheight,
        width=0.88\paperwidth,
        coltext=white,
        skin=bicolor,
        valign=center,
        halign=left,
        interior style={%%%
          left color=structure!95!black,
          right color=structure
          }%%%
        ]
        \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty
        \insertframetitle    
        \else 
        \insertframetitle|\small \insertframesubtitle
        \fi
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{textblock*}
  \hfill
  \begin{textblock*}{0.118\paperwidth}(0.882\paperwidth,0\paperheight)
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        arc=0pt,
        boxrule=0pt,
        left skip =0pt,
        right skip=0pt,
        %height=\frametitleheight,width=0.15\paperwidth,
        height=0.10\paperheight,
        width=0.12\paperwidth,
        coltext=white,
        skin=bicolor,
        valign=center,
        halign=right,
        interior style={%%%
          left color=structure,
          right color=structure!90!white
          }%%%
        ]
        \scriptsize \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
    \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{textblock*}
  \vspace{0.10\paperheight}
  }%%%%
\makeatother

% footline  
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \vspace{2mm}
  \begin{textblock*}{1.01\paperwidth}(0.92\paperwidth,0.96\paperheight)
    {logo here}
  \end{textblock*}
}

\mode
<all> 

%----------------------------------------
%   Path of Figures
%----------------------------------------


%------------------------------------------
%           begin of document
%------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\section{first }

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Limits}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Limits}
  \framesubtitle{Monotone Sequence}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item first
    \item second
    \item third
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------
%             end of  document
%------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great!  I've made a mistake..... Thank you so much  for your immediate help!